# Using python-telegram-bot API, how to create tests where I use fake-user-bots to type commands into a group chat and have my bot instance respond

Tags: telegram, python-telegram-bot

I am using `python-telegram-bot` to create tests for bot commands typed in a Telegram group chat. My first try at this was to create bots that would be users, and use `user.send_message("/start")` so that my `telegram.Bot` instance would handle the logic. However, it seems that the bot is built to respond to humans only. Reading through the documentation I see that there is `telegram.Chat` and `telegram.User`.

```
chat = Chat(id=0, type="group")
user = User(id=123, first_name="Sam", is_bot=False)
```

I cannot figure out how to connect these two objects. I would think I could do something like `chat.add_user()` and `user.send_message(chat_id)` but neither of those methods seems to exist. the user object has a `send_message()` method doesn't take Chat object, or chat_id. How do I connect the Chat and User objects so that I can test various telegram.Bot commands?

Answer (score 0):

First,you have to go Telegram and search official Bot Father account. Enter /newbot to create your personal bot.

Second, please create a group and add your bot into it. In order to obtain the chat/group ID for the group you created. You can access this link https://api.telegram.org/bot/getUpdates and replace ""  with your bot token. Type /abc and tag your bot in the group chat. After you refresh the page, you will see a json return. Please search for chat id (-5xxxxxx).

Third, i assumed you have install python telegram bot in your environment.
Create python file and code as below:

```
from telegram import *
from telegram.ext import *

def sendtext(update,context):
   updater.bot.sendMessage(chatid, "Hello World")
                           
updater = Updater("your token")
chatid= yourchatID
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('sendtext',sendtext))
print("Started Polling")
updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()
```

Run the code and type /sendtext in the group. You will see helloworld.